# MarkLogic Copy through MLCP - Errors

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

When I am doing bulk load from one db to another db using mlcp, I am getting below timeout errors. Any ideas

The commands to execute:

> [root@mlcp bin]# sh mlcp.sh copy -mode local -input_host x.x.x.x -input_port 8000 -input_database p2a-aws-prod-00-content -copy_collections false -copy_permissions false -copy_properties false -copy_quality false -input_username admin -input_password admin -output_host x.x.x.x -output_port 8000 -output_database p2a-aws-bldstb-00-content -output_username admin -output_password admin

I see this in the logs:

> 17/03/31 05:49:05 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 66%
>   2017-03-31 05:49:16.951 SEVERE [13] (StreamingResultSequence.next): RequestException instantiating ResultItem 85129: Time limit exceeded
>    com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: SVC-EXTIME: Time limit exceeded
>    [Session: user=admin, cb=#12474893908780766241 [ContentSource: user=admin, cb=p2a-aws-prod-00-content [provider: address=00-prod-db-02.highroads.local/10.46.13.182:8000, pool=0/64]]]
>    [Client: XCC/8.0-6.3, Server: XDBC/8.0-5.1]

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a guess without knowing more about data sizes, and connection between the systems, but I'd expect there are a few big files in there, and it takes too long to copy them over in one transaction. Try decreasing `batch_size` and or `transaction_size`. You could also consider lowering `thread_count` as the threads might be competing for network bandwidth..

HTH!